# Why is <deny users="?" /> included in the following example?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, authorization

The `?` wildcard represents unauthenticated users while `*` represents all users, authenticated and unauthenticated. My book shows the following example of URL authorization:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="dan,matthew" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

But doesn’t the above code have the same effect as :

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="dan,matthew" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

or did the author also include  `<deny users="?" />` rule for a reason?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

ASP.NET grants access from the configuration file as a matter of precedence.  In case of a potential conflict, the first occurring grant takes precedence.  So,

```
deny user="?"
```

denies access to the anonymous user.  Then

```
allow users="dan,matthew"
```

grants access to that user.  Finally, it denies access to everyone.  This shakes out as everyone except dan,matthew is denied access.

Edited to add: and as @Deviant points out, denying access to unauthenticated is pointless, since the last entry includes unauthenticated as well.  A good blog entry discussing this topic can be found at: [Guru Sarkar's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx)

Answer (score 43):

"At run time, the authorization module iterates through the allow and deny elements, starting at the most local configuration file, until the authorization module finds the first access rule that fits a particular user account. Then, the authorization module grants or denies access to a URL resource depending on whether the first access rule found is an allow or a deny rule. The default authorization rule is . Thus, by default, access is allowed unless configured otherwise."

Article at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aeskccd(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
deny = * means deny everyone
deny = ? means deny unauthenticated users
```

In your 1st example deny * will not affect dan, matthew  since they were already allowed by the preceding rule.

According to the docs, here is no difference in your 2 rule sets.

Answer (score 4):

Example 1 is for asp.net applications using forms authenication.  This is common practice for internet applications because user is unauthenticated until it is authentcation against some security module.

Example 2 is for asp.net application using windows authenication.  Windows Authentication uses Active Directory to authenticate users.  The  will prevent access to your application.  I use this feature on intranet applications.

Answer (score -1):

**See this two links:**

**deny Element for authorization (ASP.NET Settings Schema)**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8aeskccd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

**allow Element for authorization (ASP.NET Settings Schema):**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/acsd09b0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question? Answers are expected to stand on their own with links used for reference.