# Windows authorization in an asp.net mvc4 application

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, authorization

I have an authorization error in my asp.net mvc4 application. My account admin of my machine is this one

[image: admin]

my session properties:

[image: se]

in my web.config file i put this snippet:

```
 <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow  users = "Lamloumi" />
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

when i launch the application, i can't access to it.

What is the reason of this error? how can i fix my code?

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831994/why-is-deny-users-included-in-the-following-example), this may help. a similar question has been asked before

Comment: no it didn't change any thing!! i can't see the difference . Also, if i put ` <authorization>
  <deny  users = "Lamloumi" />
   </authorization>` i can access to the website!! why?

Comment: i put `string s = User.Identity.Name;` in the controller , the value of s is empty string!!!!

Comment: can u try this once httpcontext.current.user.identity.name

Comment: httpcontext didn't contains the attribute current !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add domain name to `allow`:

```
 <allow users="DomainName\UserName" />
```

Comment: How can i know the domainname?

Comment: i did this `<allow users="myipadress\Lamloumi" />` but it didn't work

Comment: please see my edit: i put `<deny users="WORKGROUP\Afif" />` but i still can access to the application

Comment: @Lamloumi I don't have any more idea! :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
<configuration>
<authentication mode="Windows" />
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow  users = "Lamloumi" />
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: `<authentication mode="Windows" />` can't be outside `configuration` tag

Comment: i think the problem is in the account because if i put ` <authorization> <deny users = "Lamloumi" /> </authorization>` i can access to the application

Comment: i put `string s = User.Identity.Name;` in the controller , the value of s is empty string!!!!

Comment: You mean `Web.config` file?

Comment: No i didn't create a user , it is an asp.net mvc4 from the scratch and i changed the authentification and authorization tags

Comment: @Lamloumi excuse me,I thinked similar forms auth! try adding domain name!